# Hibernate - ManyToMany using unique property of one of the mapped tables

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, jpa

Hibernate doesn't let me do a join table with a unique field "docket", no matter if I specify the "referencedColumnName = "docket"" (i thought the idea of this property was to tell Hibernate which field to use, in case it is not the primary key).

Database tables:

```
    student
---------------
  id (PK) | docket (UNIQUE)

  inscription
---------------
course_id | docket

inscription's PK is (course_id, docket)

    course
---------------
     id (PK)
```

The above problems raise with the following configuration:

On Student Entity:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
            name="inscription",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "docket", name="docket"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
)
private List<Course> studentCourses;
```

On Course Entity:

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "studentCourses")
private List<Student> students;
```

What causes the problem is that, when project is deployed, Hibernate executes the statement:

```
alter table public.inscription add constraint FKp625s5r1hmlggpgeq4x2nju91 foreign key (docket) references public.student
```

which is (of course) incorrect, as it is not specifying that docket is a unique field.

What it should be doing is:

```
alter table public.inscription add constraint FKp625s5r1hmlggpgeq4x2nju91 foreign key (docket) references public.student(docket)
```

but I don't know how can I tell it to do so.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: _referencedColumnName_ in general is for cases where you have multiple PK fields on an end of the relation, so you can line up the different PK column(s) with the equivalent column(s) in the join table. There is nothing in the JPA spec that I'm aware of that allows use of non-PK fields for joining; sure a JPA provider could allow it, but yours seemingly isn't.

Comment: Thank you for commenting! However, as far as I know, each database table can have only PK defined, and the other ID's of the table need to be defined as UNIQUE. Both PK and UNIQUE are used as indexes by database implementation, but the difference is how data is organized within the database (it is transparent to db users).
That's why I thought that with PK, JPA documentation was referring to any of a table's IDs (PK + UNIQUE constraints).
Perhaps, it is referring to a column of a composite PK, and I misunderstood the documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer at the official documentation.

From JPA 2.0 documentation: http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/:

> 11.1.21 JoinColumn Annotation
>
> The JoinColumn annotation is used to specify a column for joining an entity association or element
>   collection.
>
> ...
>
> The name annotation element defines the name of the foreign key column. The remaining annotation
>   elements (other than referencedColumnName) refer to this column and have the same semantics as
>   for the Column annotation.
>
> If the referencedColumnName element is missing, the foreign key is assumed to refer to the primary
>   key of the referenced table.
>
> **Support for referenced columns that are not primary key columns of the referenced table is optional.
>   Applications that use such mappings will not be portable.**

So, perhaps, what was going on was that Hibernate does not have this feature implemented, as it is not mandatory.

What I did to fix it was to modify the inscription table, replacing each field by the corresponding primary key.

Answer (score 1):

> (i thought the idea of this property was to tell Hibernate which field to use, in case it is not the primary key)

Your assumption is in contradiction with the [JPA 2.0 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/)  provided you are using Hibernate as an implementation of the JPA because the following extract states that you have to join on primary keys. It doesn't say anything about unique fields:

> **2.10.4 Bidirectional ManyToMany Relationships**
>
> Assuming that:
>
> - Entity A references a collection of Entity B.
> - Entity B references a collection of Entity A.
> - Entity A is the owner of the relationship.
>
> The following mapping defaults apply:
>
> - Entity A is mapped to a table named A.
> - Entity B is mapped to a table named B.
>
> There is a join table that is named A_B (owner name first). This join table has two foreign key columns. One foreign key column refers to table A and has the same type as the primary key of table A. The name of this foreign key column is formed as the concatenation of the following:
>   the name of the relationship property or field of entity B; "_"; the name of the **primary key column in table A**.
>
> The other foreign key column refers to table B and has the same type as the primary key of table B. The name of this foreign key column is formed as the concatenation of the following: the name of the relationship property or field of entity A; "_"; the name of the **primary key column in table B**.

(I added the format; the text is the original quotation from the specification.)

**docket** is not primary key in your case and therefore you cannot join on it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you please add the link from where you quoted the answer? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wanted to give the source link, but thought it is easy to find. [Herr](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) it is, any how.

Comment: Thanks! 
As you say, the documentation says "_The following mapping defaults apply:.._".
However, JPA provides different tools to avoid using these default configurations, and that is what I am looking for. I am pretty sure they should exists, as what I want to do is possible directly writing the command on the database.
If you may find those tools (annotations' attributes), please let me know.
Again, thank you for spending your time with this! I really appreciate it.

Comment: The term _defaults_ here is about the names of the tables and columns generated by the persistence provider if the user does not define their own. But the foreign key refers to a primary key. You can read this also in [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/manual/en-US/html/ch07.html#collections-bidirectional).